# Typo3 scheduler logs

Tags: typo3, scheduler

I've scheduled an LDAP FE users import (ig_ldap_sso_auth) for a certain site, tried it manually and it did not run.
The message was "Some or all imports failed. Synchronisation was aborted. Check your settings or your network connection".
Is there another place on the Typo3 folder regarding this site on which I can find some more info?
I've tailed /site/log/error.log yet but found nothing.
Thanks in advance,
Fabiano

Comment: I do not know the extension, but looking into the ImportUsers.php class there are 2 types of errors. 

For each LDAP configuration it tries to connect on line 131, if this fails it will continue and it will show you the message u describe. 

If the connection is succesfull it could have given you an error if there where no users for this configuration. 

Looking into https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/igLdapSsoAuth/blob/master/Classes/Library/Ldap.php it uses the Logmanager 

Try the /var/ folder in the root of your project or check table sys_log.